# Finding coefficients in powers of polynomials $x+2$, $x+1$, $2x+1$.

Tags: combinations, binomial-coefficients

Question-
Let $n$ be a positive integer.
Select the correct expression for each of the following:

The coefficient of $^$
in $(2+)^ $
is -

The coefficient of $^$
in $(1+)^$
is-

The coefficient of $^$
in $(1+2)^$
is-

I’m having difficulty with these questions- how shall i approach them.
I know that the cardinality of the set is $(2^n)$
But how will this be applied when we have $x^k$ ?

Comment: What is the purpose of ={1,2,3,…,}? It doesn't seem to appear anywhere in the rest of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use Newton's binom formula :
$$ (a+b)^n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} a^k b^{n-k}$$

So in your question :

- $(2+x)^n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} x^k2^{n-k}$, so the coefficient in $x^k$ is $\binom{n}{k} 2^{n-k}$
- $(1+x)^n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} x^k$, so the coefficient in $x^k$ is $\binom{n}{k}$
- $(2x+1)^n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} (2x)^k$, so the coefficient in $x^k$ is $\binom{n}{k} 2^{k}$

Comment: Shubham Johri what did you edit in my answer? (i can see no change)

Comment: This makes sense thank you

Comment: For the last one where did the 1 go when putting in the summation?

Comment: $1^{n-k} = 1$ so it does not appear in the sum